# Ride on rightmost lane that goes straight or right yield to drivers?

Tags: road, traffic, us

Sometimes I ride in the middle of a right most  lane that can go either straight or right.  Sometimes I get honked at red light cause drivers want me to move so they can pass me and make right turn.  Is it cool if I block the whole lane during red light? USA

[image]

Comment: Where are you? Rules and customs differ. Here we drive on the left, but our highway code tells drivers not to overtake just before turning off; taking the lane is a good way to encourage them to follow the rules even if it annoys a few. Your turn on right rule complicates matters though. I know what I'd try but there might be good reasons not to

Comment: If you are forced by the infrastructure to behave as a car would, then at a junction like this do what you would do in a car. You may have to be brave to hold your nerve against drivers who disagree, which is why "vehicular cycling" is not a long-term solution to inclusive mobility.

Comment: Clarifying - In the US, some locations permit a "free right turn on red light" so that traffic may pass through a red light as though it was green,  Since they drive on the right, its the smallest turn, and the mirrored version of a left-turn for English Commonwealth and Japanese road users.    I'm not aware of any other country that permits a turn through a red lightl; its much more common to have a green turning arrow light if that suits the intersection, or a "free turn"  which is controlled by a Give Way/Yield sign not the lights.

Comment: @Criggie I wouldn't describe a right turn on red in the US as passing through as if it was a green light. I think slightly more accurate is that it permits treating a red light as a stop sign for the purposes of turning right.

Comment: @GageMartin, it is a known fact (in some circles at least) that many people walking and cycling are forgotten by the drivers going right on red. So people from countries where this rule is not common see this as 'very dangerous'.

Comment: @Willeke I agree it is incredibly dangerous and shouldn't exist

Answer (score 4):

I do this regularly biking in the US. Taking the lane at an intersection reduces many dangers at intersections. If there was a car in the lane that was going straight the cars behind would also not be able to turn right on red. At the light, you are moving at exactly the same speed as a stopped car going straight and so there is really no reason for you to not use the same amount of space.

I am not a lawyer and the exact laws around biking vary between states in the US so this is not legal advice. Though for reference my state would require me to ride "as far to the right as is safe/reasonable" so I believe that my suggestions follow this.

Also as an aside, cars turning right on red is really dangerous and shouldn't be a normal thing.

Comment: I generally agree. I will get to the *left* of a straight/right lane to allow traffic to turn right on the inside, but I won't put myself in a position to be right-hooked.

Answer (score 0):

At least in Austria and Germany the only situation where you can be required to drive on the left is when taking a left turn. (e.g. Austrian STVO: [§ 12. Einordnen](https://www.ris.bka.gv.at/NormDokument.wxe?Abfrage=Bundesnormen&Gesetzesnummer=10011336&FassungVom=2021-03-05&Artikel=&Paragraf=12&Anlage=&Uebergangsrecht=))

Per default you have to drive as far right as is reasonable.

That being said, if it doesn’t endanger or inconvenience you, it doesn’t hurt to accommodate other driver’s needs.

Comment: Risking a right hook by encouraging a driver to pass immediately before turning doesn't seem to be a reasonable position to place yourself in, even if you're expecting to stop. IMO taking the lane is as far right as reasonable for safety.

Comment: @ChrisH I agree that drivers shouldn't be passing here. If the OP did want to let a car pass and turn here I would strongly encourage the OP to move to the left part of the lane so the car passes on the right and then turns which removes the danger of a right hook.

Comment: It all depends on the legislation. In some places when making a left turn on a multi-lane road you must stop at the right side of the road, get off the bike, cross at the zebra crossing and continue your ride.

Comment: @GageMartin: Yes, that’s what I had in mind. *If* the lane is wide enough to allow a car to pass on your right without endangering yourself. Similarly to taking a left turn on a wide intersection without separate left turning lane where you position yourself towards the middle of the road and cars who want to go straight ahead can pass you on your right. (all assuming right hand traffic)

Comment: *Per default you have to drive as far right as is reasonable.*  The usual word used is "practicable", which is distinctly different from "reasonable" or "practical".  "Ride as far right as practicable" effectively means "ride to the right unless there is ***any*** reason that you ***might believe*** you need to not do so."  If you can articulate a reason for not riding all the way to the right, you are riding "as far right as practicable".  There's a reason that the word used is "practicable".

Comment: English is not my native language, I’m not sure about the nuanced difference between practicable and reasonable. The Austrian [StVO § 7 Abs. 1](https://www.ris.bka.gv.at/NormDokument.wxe?Abfrage=Bundesnormen&Gesetzesnummer=10011336&FassungVom=2021-03-05&Artikel=&Paragraf=7) does use „zumutbar“ which translates to “reasonable” and in my opinion makes more sense. For example if there is dirt or debris on the right edge you don’t have to drive there even though it would be possible (practicable) but it’s not reasonable.

Comment: Encouraging motorists to pass you without safety distance is never a smart move, imho. That's exactly why they expect us to not require safety distances, because we encourage their dangerous behavior. Whenever there is a normal sized lane, the lane is entirely yours, simply because motorists cannot accommodate the required safety distance while passing without switching lanes. They wouldn't honk at motorcycles either, even though they have exactly the same width as a bike.